# Unbound local error inside try block in python

Tags: python

When I use a try block in python to run an aws command, I get an 'unbound local error':

```
  File ".\aws_iam_utils.py", line 1939, in create_roles
    if create_role_response == 200:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'create_role_response' referenced before assignment
```

This is the the try block that causes the error:

```
try:    
    create_role_response = (iam_client.create_role(RoleName=role_name,AssumeRolePolicyDocument=policy_doc, Description=role_description)['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'])
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An exception has occurred: {e}")
```

If I comment out the try block and run that command the script works and there is no error.

Here is the whole function:

```
def create_roles(iam_client, aws_account):
    role_name = input("Enter the role name: ")
    if role_name == 'rl-company-admin':
        policy_doc = create_pol_rl_company_admin()
        role_description = 'rl-company-admin gives users admin access to the account.'
        policy_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess'
    elif role_name == 'rl-netops':
        policy_doc = create_pol_rl_netops()
        role_description = 'rl-netops gives users read only access to the account.'
        policy_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/ReadOnlyAccess'
    elif role_name == 'rl-company-read-only':
        policy_doc = create_pol_rl_company_read_only()
        role_description = 'rl-company-read-only gives users read only access to the account.'
        policy_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/ReadOnlyAccess'
    try:    
        create_role_response = (iam_client.create_role(RoleName=role_name,AssumeRolePolicyDocument=policy_doc, Description=role_description)['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'])
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An exception has occurred: {e}")

    # Verify that console login was created
    if create_role_response == 200:
        print(Fore.GREEN + f"Role: {role_name} created.")
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        print(Fore.RED + f"Role: {role_name} not created.")
        time.sleep(5)

    try:
        attach_policy_response = (iam_client.attach_role_policy(PolicyArn=policy_arn,RoleName=role_name)['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'])
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An exceltion has occurred: {e}")

    # Verify that console login was created
    if attach_policy_response == 200:
        print(Fore.GREEN + f"Policy arn: {policy_arn} attached to: {role_name}.")
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        print(Fore.RED + f"Policy Arn: {policy_arn} attached to: {role_name}.")
        time.sleep(5)
```

Why does adding a try block cause the script to not recognize `create_role_response`?

Comment: can you add the remaining code? it's hard to tell what's happening behind the scenes :)

Comment: Just did. Thanks.

Comment: initializing 'create_role_response' is failing, then you are using it inside the if statement, probably you should move the if/else block inside the try block.

Comment: add `nonlocal create_role_response` after try:

Comment: Does it print the message in the `Except` suite?